# ngFor Loop creates an overflow in body div

Tags: html, css, angular, overflow

I'm rendering datas with an ngFor loop, the problem is that it cause the body to add an overflow with the size of the datas, example : I want to render datas inside 50% of the page and to see the others you'll need to scroll with an overflow **inside** the **data div**.

P.S : I've already tried with **vh** in CSS and `overflow-y: hidden` doesn't solve my problem

If anyone have a fix for it I'll be really glad to ear it, thank's in advance! Don't hesitate to tell me if things are unclear

**Picture of the page :**

[image]

**HTML sample**

```
<div  class="projectsContainer container hauteur" id="hauteur" >
<li   class="flex-row bb pt5 pb5 flex-noshrink mh20" *ngFor="let p of Projects.data | paginate: {itemsPerPage: itemsPerPage,currentPage: currentPage,totalItems: totalItems};" value="{{p.id}}"  >
  <a  class="flex2 pointeur" [routerLink]=" (['/Project',p.id])" (change)="currentIndex = $event.target.value" >{{p.code}}</a>
  <a class="flex4"  >{{p.title}}</a>
  <span class="flex2">{{p.created_at}}</span>
  <span class="flex2">{{p.createdby_name}}</span>
  <span class="flex2">{{p.updated_at}}</span>
  <span class="flex2">{{p.updatedby_name}}</span>
  <span class="flex2">{{p.pricelist_label}}</span>
  <span class="flex2 pl10">{{p.country_label}}</span>
  <span class="flex2 text-align-right mb5">{{p.total_fourniture}}</span>
  <a (click)="openModal(template)" class="flex-row bb pt5 pointeur pb5 flex-noshrink mh20"><img src="{{this.trash}}" class="trash"></a>
  <a class="flex-row bb pt5 pointeur pb5 flex-noshrink mh20" (click)="openModal(template2)"><img src="{{this.clip}}" class="clip"></a>
 </li>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.container {
 padding-top: 15px;
 width: 100%;
 margin-right: unset;
 margin-left: unset;
 max-width: unset;
}

.projectsContainer{
  padding-top: 15px;
  width: 97%;
  margin-left: 10px;
  max-width: unset;
  overflow-y: auto;
 }

.hauteur{
 height: 60vh !important;
}

.flex-row{
 display: flex;
 flex-direction: row;
}

.pr5{
 padding-bottom: 5px;
 }

.pt5{
 padding-top: 5px;
 }

.flex2{
 flex: 2;
 }
```

**EDIT**

What happens when I use `overflow-y: hidden` in body [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems the overfow you want to take off is the one of html or the body.

Try this:

```
html, body {
 overflow-y: hidden;
}
```

If the problem is that the element with the scroll you want to preserve ( `flex-row` I presume ) goes out the page set it a height so that it fits on the page:

```
.flex-row {
 display: flex;
 flex-direction: row;
 height: calc(100vh - 200px)
}
```

changing the 200px for the height of the above elements + the height of your bottom.

Comment: The problem when I do this is that, on little screens ( like laptot ) you cant acces all datas and can't go to the next page cause it's hidden under the page

Comment: easy, then use media queries to remove it only for little screens I update the answer in a minute

Comment: I still can't access all, I think the problem might comes from my footer which doesn't know there's the **next page** option so it's hidded under it, check the edit I've made

Comment: maybe you could create a http://codepen.io with an example of the html you have, it's difficult to guess otherwise

Comment: I think it will be to hard to reproduce... The problem comes from the fact that my "data table" goes way lower than the actual screen, it doesn't fit just inside the div as I want it to be, so, without the body overflow some datas are "kept" lower than the actual screen size

Comment: OK, I see, then I have a better idea, don't use the responsive meta tag as it can make the experience worse if your website isn't specifically designed to be responsive. Just set a height for the `.flex-row`  element which doesn't exceed the body, I'll update the answer again

Answer (score 1):

Try to add  this:

```
@media (min-width: 769px) {
    body {
     overflow: hidden;
    }
}
```

That should solve the issue.

Comment: The problem when I do this is that, on little screens ( like laptot ) you cant acces all datas and can't go to the next page cause it's hidden under the page

Comment: I've edit my answer, add a media query at the breakpoint as needed.

Comment: I still can't access all, I think the problem might comes from my footer which doesn't know there's the next page option so it's hidded under it, check the edit I've made